# Implementing AfterViewInit causes an endless loop of event invokations

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have a very strange problem. The following code produces an endless loop of invocations. Possibly only during server side rendering but I am not sure about that.

```
import { Component, AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  template: '<div>nothing...</div>'
})
export class TestComponent implements AfterViewChecked {

  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    console.log('wtf');
  }
}
```

The exact error message is as follows:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> NodeInvocationException: The Node invocation timed out after 60000ms.
>   You can change the timeout duration by setting the
>   InvocationTimeoutMilliseconds property on NodeServicesOptions.
>
> The first debugging step is to ensure that your Node.js function
>   always invokes the supplied callback (or throws an exception
>   synchronously), even if it encounters an error. Otherwise, the .NET
>   code has no way to know that it is finished or has failed.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance+d__13.MoveNext()

Funny enough compiling the ASP .Net Core project without implementing ngAfterViewChecked and THEN implementing it and injecting it with the HMR causes no error. Thats why I believe that the error might only be occure during the server side rendering step?

Comment: Just found a possible lead: https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal/issues/276

Comment: It seems to be exactly what I am looking for yet they closed the issue by saying: "Fixed as zones PR went through to clean it up." - what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The `ngAfterViewChecked` is called 3 times everytime the component detects some changes. Probably your server is talking to this component, or simply you're istantiating it somewhere. Another time i had this issue when i was asking something (with EventListener) from the component, same loop. Use ngAfterViewInit instead. Or try with ngAfterComponentChecked, but i'm not sure this would work.

Comment: Unfortunately this is exactly what I cannot use as ngAfterViewInit is only called once. I need a hook which will be called everytime the View changes ;-)

Comment: what do you want to subscribe for change? If you're waiting for a ngModel change you can use the double binding with `(ngModelChange)="yourFunction($event)"`